Could not cast prevote: previously known block 0x_ has disappeared
The finalization is blocked on our development chain and I have these logs:
2024-07-12 19:37:00 ✨ Imported #2208390 (0x85e0…1a0a)    
2024-07-12 19:37:01  Idle (14 peers), best: #2208390 (0x85e0…1a0a), finalized #2208388 (0x8ab5…262b), ⬇ 17.1kiB/s ⬆ 10.6kiB/s    
2024-07-12 19:37:06  Idle (14 peers), best: #2208390 (0x85e0…1a0a), finalized #2208388 (0x8ab5…262b), ⬇ 12.9kiB/s ⬆ 7.7kiB/s    
2024-07-12 19:37:11  Idle (14 peers), best: #2208390 (0x85e0…1a0a), finalized #2208388 (0x8ab5…262b), ⬇ 20.6kiB/s ⬆ 2.8kiB/s    
2024-07-12 19:37:11 ✨ Imported #2208391 (0xc371…9ff3)    
2024-07-12 19:37:12 ✨ Imported #2208389 (0x28d5…1ceb)    
2024-07-12 19:37:12 ♻️  Reorg on #2208391,0xc371…9ff3 to #2208390,0xc51c…8f1a, common ancestor #2208388,0x8ab5…262b    
2024-07-12 19:37:12 ✨ Imported #2208390 (0xc51c…8f1a)    
2024-07-12 19:37:12 Encountered error finding best chain containing 0xc5aa6d4d5929c8bd22af44f51db17bb5121e248d5eb7e1482f92c90ee5f2c625: couldn't find target block: Chain lookup failed: Requested a finality target using a base 0xc5aa6d4d5929c8bd22af44f51db17bb5121e248d5eb7e1482f92c90ee5f2c625 not in the best chain 0xc51c605ee2f0b94656361fb16a6db71898c2351a292869f7e3d7cd4bf8da8f1a    
2024-07-12 19:37:12 Could not cast prevote: previously known block 0xc5aa6d4d5929c8bd22af44f51db17bb5121e248d5eb7e1482f92c90ee5f2c625 has disappeared    
2024-07-12 19:37:14 ✨ Imported #2208391 (0xfbc2…01b4)    
2024-07-12 19:37:16  Idle (14 peers), best: #2208389 (0xc5aa…c625), finalized #2208389 (0xc5aa…c625), ⬇ 11.2kiB/s ⬆ 14.5kiB/s    
2024-07-12 19:37:18 Sending fatal alert BadCertificate    
2024-07-12 19:37:21  Idle (14 peers), best: #2208389 (0xc5aa…c625), finalized #2208389 (0xc5aa…c625), ⬇ 4.2kiB/s ⬆ 40.4kiB/s    
2024-07-12 19:37:26  Idle (15 peers), best: #2208389 (0xc5aa…c625), finalized #2208389 (0xc5aa…c625), ⬇ 2.4kiB/s ⬆ 1.4kiB/s    
2024-07-12 19:37:31  Idle (15 peers), best: #2208389 (0xc5aa…c625), finalized #2208389 (0xc5aa…c625), ⬇ 3.1kiB/s ⬆ 1.0kiB/s    
2024-07-12 19:37:36 ♻️  Reorg on #2208391,0xfbc2…01b4 to #2208392,0xad85…569b, common ancestor #2208388,0x8ab5…262b    
2024-07-12 19:37:36 ✨ Imported #2208392 (0xad85…569b)    
2024-07-12 19:37:36  Idle (13 peers), best: #2208392 (0xad85…569b), finalized #2208389 (0xc5aa…c625), ⬇ 1.2kiB/s ⬆ 2.4kiB/s    
2024-07-12 19:37:38 ✨ Imported #2208392 (0x6c9c…7d29)    
2024-07-12 19:37:41  Idle (14 peers), best: #2208392 (0xad85…569b), finalized #2208389 (0xc5aa…c625), ⬇ 9.3kiB/s ⬆ 3.1kiB/s    
2024-07-12 19:37:42 ✨ Imported #2208393 (0x808f…be7a)    
2024-07-12 19:37:42 ✨ Imported #2208393 (0x1e83…2588)    
2024-07-12 19:37:46  Idle (14 peers), best: #2208393 (0x808f…be7a), finalized #2208389 (0xc5aa…c625), ⬇ 1.6kiB/s ⬆ 3.9kiB/s    
2024-07-12 19:37:51  Idle (14 peers), best: #2208393 (0x808f…be7a), finalized #2208389 (0xc5aa…c625), ⬇ 3.1kiB/s ⬆ 0.9kiB/s    
2024-07-12 19:37:54  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x808f350316c928f2c17f5843f1b1e3742a649a65dc3103bbea0b0fe9d664be7a    
2024-07-12 19:37:54  Prepared block for proposing at 2208394 (8 ms) [hash: 0x513f9747d8a7edb4bb4b572428792721af144b83cfe35513898f5ca5c2ed6a59; parent_hash: 0x808f…be7a; extrinsics (1): [0x3488…c384]    
2024-07-12 19:37:54  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 2208394. Hash now 0x835ade6718d434b7be372885d5699486bff3e07cff8a02276679518baea26548, previously 0x513f9747d8a7edb4bb4b572428792721af144b83cfe35513898f5ca5c2ed6a59.    
2024-07-12 19:37:54 ✨ Imported #2208394 (0x835a…6548)

I would like to know where does this line come from:

2024-07-12 19:37:12 Could not cast prevote: previously known block 0xc5aa6d4d5929c8bd22af44f51db17bb5121e248d5eb7e1482f92c90ee5f2c625 has disappeared

It seems that my validator node was unable to cast its grandpa prevote for a finalized block that disappeared.
My node is running on polkadot-sdk v1.6.0 and there was only a minor runtime upgrade on the network.

Seems to be linked to issue https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/3487.
Due to the reorg
2024-07-12 19:37:12 ♻️  Reorg on #2208391,0xc371…9ff3 to #2208390,0xc51c…8f1a, common ancestor #2208388,0x8ab5…262b    

it was impossible to cast vote for the block that disappeared.
The fix is published in https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/5153
Credits to @bgallois on Duniter Forum for finding the issue.
